# return failure in A* algorithm Pseudocode

Tags: java, algorithm, traversal, pseudocode

I am trying to understand what the use of the return failure at the end of the pseudocode actually does. How would it return the path calculated?

```
    // For each node, the cost of getting from the start node to that node.
    gScore := map with default value of Infinity
    // The cost of going from start to start is zero.
    gScore[start] := 0 
    // For each node, the total cost of getting from the start node to the goal
    // by passing by that node. That value is partly known, partly heuristic.
    fScore := map with default value of Infinity
    // For the first node, that value is completely heuristic.
    fScore[start] := heuristic_cost_estimate(start, goal)

    while openSet is not empty
        current := the node in openSet having the lowest fScore[] value
        if current = goal
            return reconstruct_path(cameFrom, current)

        openSet.Remove(current)
        closedSet.Add(current)
        for each neighbor of current
            if neighbor in closedSet
                continue        // Ignore the neighbor which is already evaluated.
            // The distance from start to a neighbor
            tentative_gScore := gScore[current] + dist_between(current, neighbor)
            if neighbor not in openSet  // Discover a new node
                openSet.Add(neighbor)
            else if tentative_gScore >= gScore[neighbor]
                continue        // This is not a better path.

            // This path is the best until now. Record it!
            cameFrom[neighbor] := current
            gScore[neighbor] := tentative_gScore
            fScore[neighbor] := gScore[neighbor] + heuristic_cost_estimate(neighbor, goal)

    return failure
```

Comment: It mean to return a value (e.g. null) or throw an exception, indicating that a path could not be found.

Comment: if it is to just return a value, why can't you just use **return value**?

Comment: It is to return a value that indicates **failure**. It is entirely up to you to choose what actual *value* should be returned when the method fails to find a path, so the caller can recognize it as such. A null value would be a common choice, indicating that there is no path. If the return type is an array or a list, then an empty array/list could also be an option. It is *pseudocode*. It simply means: Return a value indicating failure to find a path.